# Replacing URL of one page by the URL of another page which is framed

Tags: iframe

I am trying to load a webpage say "a.html" in a frame in the page "b.html". Also, i am running the script which replaces the url with "a.html" using history.ReplaceState({},"","/a.html") in "b.html". I am running the above script before iframe gets loaded i.e. url of the window changes from "b.html" to "a.html". But as soon as the url changes to "a.html", "a.html" page doesnt load in iframe. Whereas, if i dont run the above script, "a.html" page gets loaded in iframe. Can anyone please tell me why the webpage doesnt load in iframe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using `location.assign("/a.html")`

Comment: Yeah, i tried using location.assign("/a.html") and its working now. But, now the problem is "a.html" busts out of the frame(since it implements framebusting code). The framebusting code checks "top.location" with "self.location". Since, i have already replaced top with "a.html" using replaceState(), the framebusting code shouldn't work. But it works and busts out of the frame. Why does this happens?

Comment: That happens because its actually looking and comparing the URLs of the top and self, being different, it will bust out. You might want to modify your frame busting code to compare self to what you replaced in the state instead of the top.

Comment: I tried alert(top.location) and alert(self.location) in the frame busting code. Both are same, since the URL was modified to a.html(which is iframe's URL) using replaceState(). Still it bust out. You can also try the same. I am still not able to figure out.

Comment: Can you post all the code you have so far and I can debug it and see what's going on and post the answer.

Comment: yes sure...here is the code.
a.html's frame busting code:
   if(top.location!=self.location) {
        top.location = self.location;
}

Comment: b.html has the following script in its <head> tag.
history.replaceState({}, "", "/a.html");
window.frames["inner1"].location.assign("http://localhost/../a.html");